# ios background image on device when play video by airplay

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6, avplayer

I got a question when implement AVPlayer
When i play video by airplay on Apple TV,
my iDevice show black screen without a hint image below like native app.
My question is 
Is this image must implement by developer or what property i should set to AVPlayer?

http://flic.kr/p/dBJnf9

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything - if you are using MPMovieController or MPMovieViewControllerView and you have an airplay capable device nearby, the airplay button will automatically appear (assuming you're both on the same network) - when you push your video to the remote airplay device - the video on your device is automatically replace with this image and the video / audio then plays back on your remote device.

In your app you may want to consider some code that either prevents the device's screen from going off (without background audio services the video/audio playback will also stop when the iDevice goes into sleep) - and/or you may want to set the "App plays audio" to the "Required background modes" in the AppName-info.plist for your app.

More details here - [Is there a way to keep Airplay running if the device auto-sleeps/auto-locks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206952/is-there-a-way-to-keep-airplay-running-if-the-device-auto-sleeps-auto-locks)

Hope that helps.